# Solve system of equations in two variables

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve $$\begin{cases} { xy+x { y }^{ 4 } = 9 } \\ { x { y }^{ 6 } +x { y }^{ 9 } = 288 } \end{cases}$$

I don't know how to solve these linear equations. I used Microsoft Mathsolver. It shows X=0.5 Y=2, But I want a step-by-step solution.

Comment: Please do not put large formulas in the title line.

Comment: To @CHEUNG WAI HIN TERRENCE: Are you able to find $x$ from first equation in a given system? Another approach is to pull out $y^5$ in a second equation...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak x={9-xy^(4)}/y

Comment: @CHEUNG WAI HIN TERRENCE: I would use $x=9/(y+y^4)$...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** The first equation may be rewritten as $xy(1+y^3)=9$, and the second one as $xy^6(1+y^3)=288$.

Now you can try to use that to obtain an equation involving only $y$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-$$xy^6+xy^9=32(xy+xy^4)$$ Since $x\ne0$ we have
$$y^8+y^5-32y^3-32=(y+1)(y-2)(y^2-y+1)(y^4+2y^3+4y^2+8y+16)=0$$ The fourth factor has four non-real roots.